# Can't get the correct file path from JFileChooser

Tags: jfilechooser

I've created a JFileChooser which I use to locate a directory for a file to be saved to.

```
saveChooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
saveChooser.showSaveDialog(null);
String exportPath = saveChooser.getCurrentDirectory() + "\\exportedData.txt";
System.out.println(exportPath);
```

(I then use exportPath for my file writer)

When I choose
*C:\Users\'me'\Eclipse\workspace\'project'\files*
in the JFileChooser
the output is
*C:\Users\'me'\Eclipse\workspace\'project'\exportedData.txt*

I've tried saving to multiple locations. It seems like it always drops the last directory.
However, when I select root C:\   it uses My Documents which is the default I suppose.
I know this probably isn't the best way to save a file and opens up to a few bugs, sorry. (The file name and extension is set in code).

Comment: I've also tried adding an extra '\' to the path in the JFileChooser before approving it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would guess that you want saveChooser.getSelectedFile(), and that in this case the selected file is really a directory.  Hope that's right, didn't test.